# div wont display when page loads

Tags: html, css

I creatd two divs inside a primary wrapper and used column.But when I load my page through preloader or local host ad-section does not appear in the screen.When I inspect it, it doesnt show any identical width or height.But if I open the page throug 'open in browser' it appears.I checked all the div closing and css closing and everything is fine.I cant figure out whats the problem.Plz help.

code:

```
                <div class="details-section col l8 m12 s12">

                    contents                        

                </div><!--details-section ends-->

                <div class="ad-section col l4 m12 s12">
                    contents    

                </div><!--ad-section ends-->
```

Comment: Most likely ad-blocker ... rename your `ad-section` to something else

Comment: Thank you so much. It's adblocker. Finally I overcame it...phewwww